# Date function isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert the current year into a copyright statement and it's not working - likely because of something really basic. Any help? Thanks. :)

ps If there are any other stylistic issues, I welcome all comments.

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  // Veterinary Calculator Code
  // define variables for body weight, dehydration and ongoing losses
  $bw = $('#bodyWeight');
  $dh = $('#dehydration');
  $ol = $('#ongoingLosses');
  //  update maint, replacement, dailyRequirement and rate when bw, dh or ol changes.
  function updateDetails()
  {
    var $dr = $('#dailyRequirement');
    var $repl = $('#replacement');
    var $rt = $('#rate');
    var ol = parseInt($ol.val());
    var mt = parseInt(1.5 * (70 * (Math.pow($bw.val(), 0.75)))); // maintenance requirement
    $dr.text(mt + ' ml/24 hours');
    var rep = parseInt($bw.val() * 10 * $dh.val()); // replacement amount
    $repl.text(rep + ' ml');
    var rt = parseInt((mt + rep + ol) / 24); // total fluid rate
    $rt.text(rt + ' ml/hr');
  }
  // add event listeners for input elements

  $bw.on('change', updateDetails);
  $dh.on('change', updateDetails);
  $ol.on('change', updateDetails);
  // Insert current year into copyright statement
  var dateNow = new Date();
  var thisYear = dateNow.getFullYear();
  var elYear = $('#currentYear');
  elYear.text = thisYear;
});
```

```html
 <body>
  <div>
   <header>
    <h1>Fluid Calculator</h1>
   </header>
   

   <div>
    <fieldset id="params">
     <legend>Inputs</legend>
     <label>Body Weight (kg):</label><br />
     <input type="number" id="bodyWeight" autofocus min="0" />
     <br><br />
     <label>% Dehydration:</label><br />
     <input type="number" id="dehydration"/>
     <br /><br />
     <label>Ongoing Losses (ml):</label><br />
     <input type="number" id="ongoingLosses" />
     <br /><br />  
          
    </fieldset><br />

    <label>Daily Requirement:</label> <label class="result" id="dailyRequirement">0 ml</label> <br />
    <label>Replacement:</label> <label class="result" id="replacement">0 ml</label> <br />
    
    
    <br />
    <label> Rate (ml/hr):</label> <label class="result" id="rate">0 ml/hr</label>
   </div>

   <footer>
    <p>  
     &copy; Copyright 2014-<span id="currentYear">year</span> by VETsharp Pty Ltd
    </p>
   </footer>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vc.js"></script>
  
 </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#currentYear").text(thisYear);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked and I can now see why my code didn't. Great!

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace the text of the `currentYear` `<span>`, you need to use:

```
$('#currentYear').replaceWith(thisYear);
```